# COM object is not in the allowed list of CoCreateInstanceFromApp error in my Metro App

Tags: windows-8

I am trying to set an image as wallpaper through my windows 8 Metro App. I am getting this error when I try to do it 
"Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {75048700-EF1F-11D0-9888-006097DEACF9} using CoCreateInstanceFromApp failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). Please make sure your COM object is in the allowed list of CoCreateInstanceFromApp."
How do I register my class and make it work?

Thanks

Comment: That's only problem #2.  Problem #1 is that a store app cannot change the desktop wallpaper.

Answer (score 3):

The set of COM objects which can be accessed by a windows store app is extremely limited.  Looking at the MSDN documentation, it appears that CLSID_ActiveDesktop is not one of the classes that's allowed to be accessed by store apps.

As Hans mentioned in his comment, store apps aren't allowed to interfere with per-user state - actions like changing the desktop wallpaper count as changing user state.